# matplotlib legend location numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am beginning to use Python for my scientific computing, and I am really liking it a lot, however I am confused by a feature of the matplotlib.pylab.legend function.  In particular, the location feature allows one to specifiy the location of their legend using numbers, following this scheme:

- best -- 0
- upper right -- 1
- upper left -- 2
- lower left -- 3
- lower right -- 4
- right -- 5
- center left -- 6
- center right -- 7
- lower center -- 8
- upper center -- 9
- center -- 10

Does anyone know why you wouldn't use the ordering on the numpad? I.e. center -- 5, upper right -- 9, etc.

I am just curious if anyone knows.

Comment: You usually specify the string `'center'` in place of `10`. Try it.

Comment: well, maybe the developers were primarily coding in starbucks using their tiny teeny little numpad-less laptops.

Comment: Actually, they were deliberately mimicking matlab's behavior at the time. See the "obsolete location values" section in the documentation for MATLAB's `legend`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) show this example:

```
legend( ('label1', 'label2', 'label3'), loc='upper left')
```

Presumably, you could write `loc=2`, but why would you?  It's much more readable to use the English word.

As to why they didn't enumerate the values to align with the numeric keypad, I presume they weren't thinking about the numeric keypad at the time.

**Edit:** It's worth including here the full text of [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington)'s comment:

> Actually, they were deliberately mimicking matlab's behavior at the
>   time. See the "obsolete location values" section in the documentation
>   for MATLAB's `legend`: [mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html)